# What do quadcopter propeller specifications mean?

Tags: quadcopter, design

I'm trying to figure out the diameter of tri-blade propellers.

I found a 7x3x4.5 blade, I'm trying to understand the measurements. Is the '7' the length of the blade giving the prop a 10.5" diameter? or is the 7 the total diameter?

Answer (score 3):

7 is diameter of propeller in inches and 4.5 is pitch of propeller in inches.

Unless mentioned, propeller parameters are mentioned in inches. The Pitch of a propeller is distance covered by the propeller in one full rotation hence measured in inches. This is similar to pitch of a screw.

Comment: perhaps the 3 means it is a 3 bladed prop.